# How to pass parameters through API to be picked up by a shell script in Oozie?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, oozie, hue, oozie-workflow

I am able to submit an oozie job by by specifying the username, wf.application.path in an XML body that is sent as a POST request to the oozie server.

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>user.name</name>
    <value>cmluat</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>oozie.wf.application.path</name>
    <value>hdfs://somename/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/hue-oozie-1537788744.34/</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>Country</name>
    <value>Malaysia</value>
</property>
```

When job status is viewed (through Hue), I am able to see the above name, value pairs under 'configuration" tab.

**My question is**, how do I get my shell action (that contains a shell/python script) to take these name value pairs as inputs/ arguments (Country, Malaysia).

Is there some feature in Hue to pass tags from config.xml on to the shell action. Or better yet, is there a path on HDFS where the above config .xml passed from UI to server is stored?

---

**Side Question**
The path /user/hue/oozie/workspaces/hue-oozie-1537788744.**34**/ (which is the one provided in the XML for job submission) contains the workflow.xml, shellscript.sh, lib etc

But when i view the status of the job ID that I get as a response to job submission, clicking on the shellscript.sh visible in the DAG (through Hue) redirects me to a /user/hue/oozie/workspaces/hue-oozie-1452553957.**19**/ which does not exist (even when accessed out of Hue through terminal via hdfs user).

What is the workflow path hue-oozie-1452553957.**19** and how does it get created, what does it contain etc?

Comment: My 2 cents: don't use Hue as an "Oozie IDE" or "Oozie job launcher" if you want to build a serious process. It's just a toy for beginners, with limited Oozie feature set. For serious work... you'll have to build your own set of scripts.

Comment: Look into EL expressions, and into the XML schema for "shell extensions" (how to pass arguments, define env variables etc.)

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, True, I've stopped using Hue's workflow editor for preparing my scripts. I am making changes to workflow.xml etc directly.

But regardless. I wanted to know how to pass the variables that are sent from UI to the shell script directly. As of now I can just pass the arguments that are present in the workflow path (in the job.properties file).

Comment: Just put some ${varname} in the Editor and give default properties values or they will be prompted at workflow submission. You could also have the workflow.xml and job.properties aside in HDFS and submit them directly via the File Browser by selecting the workflow.xml.